# to to use for loop to run through objects within array and console.log if movie has been seen or not

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, for-loop

I'm new to learning coding. Having a bit of a hard time with for loops and forEach. My code is not working for some reason, and I don't know what the error is. Does anyone see anything that I need to fix?

---

```
var myMovies = [

  {name: "Gladiator",
   rating: 5,
   seen: true
  },
  {name: "Vanilla Sky",
  rating: 4.5,
  seen: true
  },
  {name: "Beautiful Mind",
  rating: 5,
  seen:true
  },
  {name: "The Happytime Murders",
   rating: 3.5,
   seen: false
  }
];
  var movies = myMovies;
for(i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
  if(movies.seen){
  console.log("You have seen " + movies.name + "-" + movies.rating);
}else
console.log("You haven't seen " + movies.name + "-" + movies.rating);
```

Comment: You can filter all seen and not seen movie like myMovies.filter(x=>x.seen ), it will return all seen movies in new array and the you can simply iterate using for loop. For not seen movies you can simply toggle the condition like x=>x.seen===false

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is your `myMovies` and `movies` variables are arrays, you need to show which index you want. Here's your fixed code:

```
var myMovies = [

  {name: "Gladiator",
   rating: 5,
   seen: true
  },
  {name: "Vanilla Sky",
  rating: 4.5,
  seen: true
  },
  {name: "Beautiful Mind",
  rating: 5,
  seen:true
  },
  {name: "The Happytime Murders",
   rating: 3.5,
   seen: false
  }
];
var movies = myMovies;
for(i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
  if(movies[i].seen){
  console.log("You have seen " + movies[i].name + "-" + movies[i].rating);
}else
console.log("You haven't seen " + movies[i].name + "-" + movies[i].rating);
```

Comment: Thankyou! I appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem. I'm always glad to help

Answer (score 2):

var myMovies = [

```
    {name: "Gladiator",
        rating: 5,
        seen: true
    },
    {name: "Vanilla Sky",
        rating: 4.5,
        seen: true
    },
    {name: "Beautiful Mind",
        rating: 5,
        seen:true
    },
    {name: "The Happytime Murders",
        rating: 3.5,
        seen: false
    }
];
var movies = myMovies;
for(i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
    if(movies[i].seen){
        console.log("You have seen " + movies[i].name + "-" + movies[i].rating);
    }else
        console.log("You haven't seen " + movies[i].name + "-" + movies[i].rating);
```

Or is it like this  I think you are mixing for and foreach

```
var myMovies = [

    {name: "Gladiator",
        rating: 5,
        seen: true
    },
    {name: "Vanilla Sky",
        rating: 4.5,
        seen: true
    },
    {name: "Beautiful Mind",
        rating: 5,
        seen:true
    },
    {name: "The Happytime Murders",
        rating: 3.5,
        seen: false
    }
];

myMovies.forEach(movies=>{
    if(movies.seen){
        console.log("You have seen " + movies.name + "-" + movies.rating);
    }else
        console.log("You haven't seen " + movies.name + "-" + movies.rating);
})
```